# Where can I take a shower at Dubai Airport?

Tags: transit, airports, layovers, hygiene, dxb

I've got two transfers between long-haul flights coming up at DXB, and I'd like to freshen up with a shower. Information on the net is outdated and contradictory, and the [official site](http://www.dubaiairport.com/en/Pages/home.aspx) is remarkably useless. I will be in the Terminal 3 (Emirates), although I'll do the long schlep to T1 and back if I need. I have no frequent flier lounge access.

What are my options for a shower?

Comment: I like this kind of posts, personal experience beats any reference. Thanks for sharing this, many people will benefit from this.

Comment: Do you have enough time for the T3-T1 walk? IIRC, there are more third party lounges in the T1 side, and a long walk can do you good after a long flight!

Comment: I've got ~3 hours both ways, so I can probably manage, but I'd prefer to take it easy in T3 though -- especially on the way back when I need to hit the duty free as well!

Comment: I found the information right there [on the official website](http://www.dubaiairports.ae/while-you-are-here/services-facilities#showers) - not sure when you looked. Also, dubaiairport.com was not the official site of the airport; the domain was bought and now redirects to dubairairports.ae (the official site).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I hereby present...

## The Exhaustingly Exhaustive Dubai Airport Shower Guide

All prices and info accurate as of June 2014.

### Marhaba lounge

The [Marhaba lounge](https://www.marhabaservices.com/source/lounge.aspx) in T3 Concourse A (between gates A2/A3) has rather nice showers, easily on a par with a four-star hotel.  A shower alone without lounge access costs Dhs 55 (~US$15), including towel and cosmetics kit (shampoo, body soap, toothbrush, shaving kit, etc).  Just beware that in the muggy Dubai summer, even "cold" water is lukewarm, and ventilation is kind of minimal so it gets pretty sauna-like pretty fast if you shower too long.  Opening the cubicle door provides rapid relief though. There might be a queue (even longer than the free shower). Overall score, **8/10**.

- Full lounge access is Dhs 190 (~US$50), which gets you a buffet, internet access, and a buggy transfer to your gate as well.
- *Bonus*: Lounge access is [free](http://www.mastercard.com/mel/personal/en/promotions/airport_lounges.html) with a "Titanium, Platinum or World" MasterCard *if* (per the [T&Cs](http://www.mastercard.com/mel/personal/en/promotions/experience_lounge_luxury_terms_dubai.html)) issued in the Middle East & Africa, although enforcement appears to be a bit loose.

[image]
[image]

### Dubai International Hotel

You can take a shower at any of the many [Dubai International Hotel](http://www.dubaiintlhotels.com/facilities-en.html) outlets, including the one in Concourse A, for US$15.  Not tested yet.

### G-Force Health Club

Access to the G Force Health Club gym (including showers), at T3 Concourse B *only*, elevator to level 5 right opposite the elevators to the Gate A trains, can be purchased for Dhs 70 (~US$19) for 1.5 hours.  The gym is basic but does the job: treadmill, stationary bike, multipurpose machine, dumbbells.  The shower, on the other hand, is rather nice, the amenity pack includes everything down to Q-tips and you even get a bathrobe.  Plus water is cooler and it doesn't steam up as badly as Marhaba's version.  Overall score, **10/10**!

[image]
[image]

### Public showers

There are clearly signposted free public showers in Coucourse A, near gate A1 right opposite the Le Clos wine shop.  These look clean but no-frills, you'll need to bring your own towel and toiletries (there is a soap dispenser), and there was a (short) queue when I came to take a look (but it might be shorter than the Marhaba lounge).  [Apparently](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k6795902-Terminal_3_Dubai_Airport_Showers_lounges_etc-Air_Travel.html) Concourse B has a similar setup at gate B13, and there are a few signs pointing the way.

Per [Sleeping in Airports](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/mideast/dubai.htm#servicesFacilities), the free showers in Terminal 3 can be found near these gates:

> Terminal 3, between Gates A1 - A24, Gates B13 - B19 and Gates C18 and C22.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you at the Dubai airport *right now*?

Comment: No, this is a few weeks off.

Comment: I had a shower last time, I don't remember the gate, but basically is rest room with a free shower.

Comment: You've taken a shower multiple times at the Dubai Airport? :O How often do you travel thru Dubai?

Comment: 27 times since 2007.  And trust me, if you're flying Australia<->Europe, you could use a shower too at the halfway mark...

Comment: Just to update here - I tried the Platinum Mastercard free entry trick at the Maharaba lounge in Q3 2016 and it didn't work - had to pay the USD $15 to get in.