# Showers Dubai terminal 3

Tags: dubai

I would like to know if there are showers in Dubai terminal 3 transit area. As we only have an hour half between flights

Answer (score 2):

Per [Sleeping in Airports](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/mideast/dubai.htm#servicesFacilities):

> Showers - Showers are available in the Gym [ see Health Club above ] and lounges [ see Airport Lounges above ]. There are also free shower facilities at the following locations: Terminal 3, between Gates A1 - A24, Gates B13 - B19 and Gates C18 and C22.

So there are free showers in each of Terminal 3's concourses.

Note that an hour and a half may not be sufficient time for a shower. The [minimum connection time](https://www.aviateworld.com/news/airline-news/emirates-reduces-flight-connection-time-in-dubai/) is at least an hour, and if you're flying Emirates, you must be at the gate [at least 20 minutes](https://www.emirates.com/us/english/plan_book/check_in_online/online-check-in.aspx) before departure. You may have time if your flight is on time, there isn't much of a wait at transfer security, the gates aren't far apart, and there's no line for the showers, but it's possible you won't have time.

**Update:** There is an exhaustive guide to the shower options at [Where can I take a shower at Dubai Airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27758/where-can-i-take-a-shower-at-dubai-airport). Note that you'll need to bring your own towel for the free showers.